# Is it better to use dictionary instead of create a class

Tags: swift

I used to do things like below:

```
class A {
   var param1:String?
   var param2:[B]?
}

class B {
   var param1:String?
   var param2:String?
   var param3:[C]?
}

class C {
   var param1:String?
   var param2:String?
}
```

But recently I found that dictionaries are more flexible. Class A can be replaced by the following dictionary.

```
[
    "param1":"some string",
    "param2":[
        "param1":"some string",
        "param2":"some string",
        "param3":[
            "param1":"some string",
            "param2":"some string"
        ],
        [
            ...
            ...
        ]
    ],
    [
        ...
        ...
    ],
    ...
]
```

If we want to add "param3" into class C, we need to modify a lot of associated code if using class. But if we use dictionaries, we can just use "param3" as if it already exists.

A dictionary is just like a runtime defined class. I am wondering should we use dictionaries to replace data storing classes (i.e. models in MVC pattern) in all situations.

Comment: Never ever use dictionaries to represent classes. You will lose all the pros of a strongly-typed language.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use you have of your model. Making small classes enables you to give each class a specific additional behavior (for example more specific isolated accessory methods or helpers). 
You can also test the model more easily by using only the piece you want and mock the other.

In general splitting responsibility is better because of maintenance and testability and clear code.

If your dictionary grows out of control then it is going to be very difficult for a newcomer on your team to use and understand the giant blob of data, rather than handling a lot of small objects with relationships between themselves.

If you add a new parameter you might need to change a lot of initializers. 
That is normal I would say.

Also it depends on how you manage the model initialization. Maybe you use a factory that hides this complexity for you inside the rest of your code. 
Or maybe you will need just to change it in your dependency injection root.

It clearly depends on the approach and scope of the object you are creating.

But in my opinion isolated objects are more reusable than a big blob of data in a dictionary

Comment: It doesn't really depend on the scope :) Using dictionaries to represent objects is just bad.

Comment: Well, if the datamodel is super small and has a super small use it might be acceptable. However I am fully for all OOP so I agree with you

Comment: The type problem arises even for objects with one property. Also, we have tuples that can solve the need of temporary objects and are still type safe.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that dictionaries are more extensible, ***but*** classes are safer.

One big unsafe thing about dictionaries is that you don't know whether a key exist or not at compile time. You have to put `guard let` or `if let` statements all over the place whenever you want to access something. If you don't do this, the app will crash at runtime when the key does not exist. Sure, you can fix it after it crashed, but you wasted a lot of time running your app and making that erroneous line of code to run and crash.

The other unsafe thing is type-unsafety. Since your dictionary contains different types of stuff, It must be a `[String: Any]`. Normally you can do this with classes:

```
someAObject.param2!.first!.param3!.first!.param1
```

If you use dictionaries you need:

```
(((dict["param2"]! as! [[String: Any]]).first!["param3"] as! [[String: Any]]).first! as! [String: Any])["param1"]
```

Just look at how much more code that is! Also, when you want a method to accept a parameter, you can write `A` or `B` or `C` if you are using classes and the method will only accept the type you specify. If you are using dictionaries, all you can write is `[String: Any]`. There is no compile time check whether that dictionary is of the acceptable type.

The third thing is about typos. If you typed a property name wrong, Xcode will tell you that even before you run the app. If you typed a dictionary key wrong, Xcode will not tell you that. You have to run that bit of code to know. Sure, you can put keys into constants, but that is very troublesome and the trouble definitely overweighs what you call "benefits" of dictionaries.

The fourth point is that dictionaries are value types. You might want some of the features of reference types.

And last but not least, you cannot add methods to dictionaries! A very important feature of classes is that they allow you to add methods and you can call them on instances of the class. If you made good use of this, you can write very readable code.

> If we want to add "param3" into class C, we need to modify a lot of associated code if using class

Not if you designed your model well. I can't think of a reason why adding a new property to a class would require you to change lots of associated code.